# Validate textboxes in asp custom control with no form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, textbox, custom-controls

I have 5 text boxes and button in a custom user control in asp.net webform.  I am having trouble trying to figure out how to validate all these text boxes before submitting.   The button does not perform postback , I need to check if text boxes are valid in jQuery , and if they are valid I will post to webmethod.

I can't figure out how to do this with jQuery Validate because you cannot use form tag in a custom control.  I also cannot use the validation that is built in .net because it needs to be validated on client side , not server side.

Right now I have onblur for each text box and they are checked with regex expression , then if they fail there is an error label that displays message.  Then submit button checks each error label to see if they = "" , but the problem is that if will obivously pass if nothing has been entered into any textbox and no errors have been shown.

Is there an easy way to validate textboxes without form tags , and check validation all on client side?

Comment: When your page loads, the custom control is rendered inside of the form tag.  I am confused why you say you can't use jquery validate?

Comment: yea , I got it to work, I just wanted to validate the custom control separately , like its a different form from the default page , but when the browser renders it, they are in the same form

Comment: You can.  jquery doesn't need a form tag?

Comment: You can simply add a standard validator to you control. By default, ASP.NET creates client-side script for validation too.